# Disabling elements of a checkbox group

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, checkbox, code-snippets

I have a checkbox group that I'm trying to target through HTML Snippets in Wordpress. When a session (denoted by one of the checkbox elements) within the group is full, the checkbox needs to be greyed out. I've tried all manner of combinations along the lines of the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementById("Mondays")[0].disabled = true;
document.getElementsById("Mondays")[1].disabled = true;
document.getElementById("Mondays")[2].disabled = true;
</script>
```

But nothing is working. Can anyone help?

This is driving me nuts, as I did this once and then lost the code!!

Comment: You cant have more than one ID of the same name. So you should use classes and getElementsByClassName. Also provide HTML so we can tell what is bad on your js script.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, one possible solution is that you meant to use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementById`.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementsByClassName("Mondays")[0].disabled = true;
document.getElementsByClassName("Mondays")[1].disabled = true;
document.getElementsByClassName("Mondays")[2].disabled = true;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I knew I'd solve it as soon as I posted it. The code should be:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementById("Mondays_12_1_1").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("Mondays_12_1_2").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("Mondays_12_1_3").disabled = true;
</script>
```

And yes, I know I had a typo in there too!

Sorry for wasting your time...